# Error importing Pygame on Ubuntu 14.04 (ImportError: libSDL-1.2.so.0: undefined symbol: _XGetRequest)

Tags: 14.04, python

I have compiled Pygame for Python 3.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 following the instructions listed [here](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileUbuntu). However, when I try to compile a Pygame program, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "game.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 133, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0: undefined symbol: _XGetRequest
```

I have read that this might be due to a library mismatch. If that's true, how can I find out what libraries are involved (other than SDL) and how can I fix it?

Comment: I believe you may need PySDL2. Not my strong suit, but this may be helpful: http://pysdl2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately the error is still there after installing PySDL2.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127730/how-to-install-pygame-on-python-3-4

Comment: I have seen that question -- unfortunately, it did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I had two SDL-1.2 libraries installed: one in `/usr/local/lib/` and one in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/`, the latter of which is the default path on Ubuntu, I believe. Removing all the SDL files at `/usr/local/lib/` solved the problem.

Comment: Nice find. I never would have guessed that.